# How to compare all row values of a column against all different values of that column using SQL and return in seperate columns

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a column that has values like this
I want to write an SQL statement to return
values in two columns which will look like this.

[input]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5GuT.png

---

[Output]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHolu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to self `JOIN` your table with `column` value unequality condition like this

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM (values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d')) t("column")
)
SELECT d1."column", d2."column"
FROM data d1
JOIN data d2 ON d1."column" != d2."column"
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM table_name
)
SELECT d1."column", d2."column"
FROM data d1
JOIN data d2 ON d1."column" != d2."column"
ORDER BY 1, 2

Answer (score 0):

select * from table t1 cross join table t2